# Group by and sum in a collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

I don't know if there's an easy way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, so I figured I might as well ask. I did search for the answer to this question, but I could not find something similar.

I have a variable called `$data` which holds a collection that looks something like this:

```
[
    "date" => "2017-10-07 10:00:00"
    "usage" => 0.423
    "costs" => 1.212
],
[
    "date" => "2017-10-07 11:00:00"
    "usage" => 0.786
    "costs" => 1.564
],
[
    "date" => "2017-10-07 12:00:00"
    "usage" => 0.542
    "costs" => 1.545
]
```

*(The data can be every hour for up to 2 months, for readability I chose to include only 3 hours in this example)*

As you can see, it's all **per hour** (which is also data I need for a different part in the code) I would like a **separate collection per day**. Is there an easy way to group by date('Ymd') and sum `usage` and `costs`? I should also mention that **not all items in the collection have all indexes**. Some don't have `usage`, some don't have `costs`. All do have `date` however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly achieve this with something like this:

```php
$collection = collect([
    [
        "date" => "2017-10-07 10:00:00",
        "usage" => 0.423,
        "costs" => 1.212
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2017-10-07 11:00:00",
        "usage" => 0.786,
        "costs" => 1.564
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2017-10-07 12:00:00",
        "usage" => 0.542,
        "costs" => 1.545
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2017-10-08 10:00:00",
        "costs" => 1.1
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2017-10-08 11:00:00",
        "usage" => 0.786,
    ],
    [
        "date" => "2017-10-08 12:00:00",
        "costs" => 1.567
    ]
]); 


return $collection->groupBy(function($row) {
    return Carbon\Carbon::parse($row['date'])->format('Y-m-d'); 
})->map(function($value, $key) {
    return [
        'usage' => $value->sum('usage'), 
        'costs' => $value->sum('costs')
    ];
});
```

The output of the above will be this:

```
Collection {#267 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "2017-10-07" => array:2 [▶]
    "2017-10-08" => array:2 [▼
      "usage" => 0.786
      "costs" => 2.667
    ]
  ]
}
```

As you can see from the above, some of the items do not have `usage` or `costs`. It will still work.

Here's also an [example](https://implode.io/iH4y9S) you can play with.